# Can you easily switch between using amazon's load balancer service and doing your own on ec2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, haproxy

If you have clients who are using your service, and pointing to your domain like:

```
api.example.com
```

If I use route 53 to manage the dns for the domain, am I able to seamlessly choose if I want to use amazon's load balancers or do this myself by running haproxy?  (servers are on ec2 also ofcourse).

Or will this require a dns change that will bring things down for a while?

Comment: On a slightly unrelated note, you'll only pay a flat rate of $18 a month for an ELB, while your HAProxy is going to start at much more than that for an m1.small.  The ELB will scale vertically and horizontally behind the scenes for the same price, while you'll pay much more for your own EC2 instance if you need to go bigger.

Answer (score 1):

It would require a DNS change, but you could run both in parallel while the DNS rolls over so it's seamless for end-users. You can also drop the TTL on the DNS record to something like 60 seconds to minimize the rollover time.